# Advanced Search button, Create Page, Modify Pages Library Setting are missing from one SharePoint Site Collection

Tags: administration, site-collection

In my Share Point 2007 server farm there is more than 150+ site Collections are created but in one SharePoint Site Collection there is some problem from this evening:

- Advanced Search button is missing from that site collection home
  page,
- Create Page option is missing from Site Action menu,
- Modify Pages Library Setting is missing from Site Settings under Site
  Action menu,
- Modify Navigation option is disabled under Site Setting under Site
  Action Menu,
- In People and Groups page, Share Point groups are not coming, to
  access those groups have to click Group option.

All above problems are coming only one site collections rest sites are working fine.
Kindly help to get me out from these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a simple Permission issue. You need at least the "Hierachy design"(don't recall exact name) permission level. Did anyone tweaked permissions levels? Or did your account had permissions given via CA using Policy of Full Control, which might have been revoked meanwhile.

C:\Marius